# Matching a String with Array of String in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement, ecmascript-5

```js
    str1 = booking_kode.substring(0, 3);
    B = ["800", "807", "826", "847", "866"];
    C = ["827", "846"];
    E = ["867", "879"];
    F = ["880", "899"];

    if (str1 = array B){
     print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n')
     comm_code = 'B000'
     print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n')
    }
    else if (str1 = array C) {
 print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n')
 comm_code = 'C000'
 print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n')
}
    else if (str1 = array E) {
 print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n')
 comm_code = 'E000'
 print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n')
}
    else if (str1 = array F) {
 print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n')
 comm_code = 'F000'
 print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n')
}
    else {
 print ('Prefix , Nilai 3 digit pertama = ' + str1 + '\n')
 comm_code = 'D000'
 print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n')
}
```

Hello,

I want to know how to match the string Str1 with the value of the Array B,C,E,F.

I mean :

```
If Str1 = 800|| 807 || 826 || 847 || 866, Then Comm_code = B000
If Str1 = 827 || 846 then Comm_code = C000
If Str1 = 867 || 879 then Comm_code = E000
If Str1 = 880 || 899 then Comm_code = F000
Else Default --> Comm_code = D000
```

Please kindly advice.

p.s. : Fyi, I'm using EcmaScript 2015 / ES5.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof):

```
str1 = booking_kode.substring(0, 3);
B = ["800", "807", "826", "847", "866"];
C = ["827", "846"];
E = ["867", "879"];
F = ["880", "899"];

if (B.indexOf(str1) > -1)
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'B000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (C.indexOf(str1) > -1)
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'C000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (E.indexOf(str1) > -1)
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'E000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (F.indexOf(str1) > -1)
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'F000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else
{
    print ('Prefix , Nilai 3 digit pertama = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'D000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
```

Comment: I have added the full code to your answer, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple if else conditions using Array.indexOf() Methods. However make sure the str1   and the values in the array  are of same variable type(string or a number).

```
   if (B.indexOf(str1) > -1 ) {   //if value exists in B 
        //do soemthing;
    } 
    else if(C.indexof(str1) >-1 ) { //if value exists in C
      //do soemthing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to solve this is use **[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** (I think it is included on `ES5` based on this [link](https://javascriptplayground.com/ecmascript-5-array-methods/)). First you can create a method that will check if an `element` is on an `array`:

```js
function arrayIncludes(arr, ele)
{
     return arr.some(function(x) {return (x === ele);});
}

console.log(arrayIncludes([1,2], 2));
console.log(arrayIncludes([1,2], 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

Then, your code can be reworked to this:

```
str1 = booking_kode.substring(0, 3);
B = ["800", "807", "826", "847", "866"];
C = ["827", "846"];
E = ["867", "879"];
F = ["880", "899"];

function arrayIncludes(arr, ele)
{
     return arr.some(function(x) {return (x === ele);});
}

if (arrayIncludes(B, str1))
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'B000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (arrayIncludes(C, str1))
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'C000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (arrayIncludes(E, str1))
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'E000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else if (arrayIncludes(F, str1))
{
    print ('Prefix , first 3 digit = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'F000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
else
{
    print ('Prefix , Nilai 3 digit pertama = ' + str1 + '\n');
    comm_code = 'D000';
    print ('Comm_Code = ' + comm_code + '\n');
}
```

Comment: `includes` is ES6 - OP can only use ES5. `indexOf` is the correct answer.

Comment: No problem @Shidersz.

Comment: @JackBashford I have reworked the code to use `Array.some()`. I have read it is available on `ES5` from different sources.